# Function runs endlessly with nested function when multiprocessed

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, concurrent.futures, nested-function

I am struggeling around with multiprocessing. I have some heavy image processing to do and wanted to make use of multi-core CPU power. However, I tried a lot and finally wanted to use the concurrent.futures module because it is more or less quite handy to use. But when I set up my programm, it runs and runs and runs and... It does not stop. The basic idea is as follows (not related to image processing, just a dummy setup):

```
import concurrent.futures as cf
import time
import multiprocessing as mp

def someFunc(seconds, multiplier=1):
    time.sleep(multiplier*seconds)
    return (f'Slept for {multiplier*seconds} s, Proc: {mp.current_process()}')

def parallelize(secs):

    factor=2

    def wrapper(sec):
        return someFunc(sec, factor)

    with cf.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results=[executor.submit(wrapper, secs) for _ in range(8)]
        for result in cf.as_completed(results):
            print(result.result())
```

So, I am running this under windows 10 in a jupyter notebook. For this reason, the functions are saved in a separate func.py file which is imported in the notebook and then runs using the if__name__=='**main**' -statement.

```
import func
if __name__=='__main__':
    func.parallelize('some_int_number')
```

The reason I do this is that I have to pass two arguments to the parallelize() function, but the submit()-method only provides one argument. I know, one could also make use of the map()-method or whatever, but for some reason (overhead?!?!) the effect of parallelizing is not very significant (I am playing with the possibilities for days now). So I wanted to try the submit()-method as proposed. 
BUT, this does not work (the script runs endlessly) and I don't know why. The problem also is, I have to handle a 'static' argument (factor) which is only known in the scope of the parallelize-function.

If I would define the wrapper-function outside the parallelize-function, the script would run as expected, but then I had the problem of the static factor variable.

Any ideas?

Greetings 
phtagen

Comment: Actually a nested function can't be used in "submit" or other process pool calls. Probably the subprocess fails with an error message which gets lost. Better add "factor" as additional parameter to "wrapper" (or omit "wrapper" completely).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. How would I add factor as an additional parameter?

Comment: Ok, what I tried so far is, to define the wrapper-function outside and set factor inside the parallelize function to global and alter it to the desired value. If I call factor from within my python script it shows the correct value, but inside the wrapper function the value of factor is not affected. So I think this might be related to concurrent.futures?!?! What would be a propper way to set factor from inside the parallelize function and than pass it correctly to wrapper, when passing it as a second argument is no option?

Comment: After the first argument to "submit" (the function to call) all further arguments are directly transferred to the called function. Just add "factor" in the "submit" call and add it as parameter in the definition of "wrapper".

Comment: OK, I will give it try and let you know. Thank you!

Comment: So, I tried your proposed solution and it worked! Thank you. I omitted the wrapper function and passed the two arguments directly to submit and I passed some_func of course. I didn't know, that the submit-method accepts multiple arguments. So finally it worked. One, hopefully, last question. I am running this on a quadcore machine. But the amount of time saved is roughly a little bit more than half the time of the seriell code (so not the dummy example above, but the real image processing, which is similar structured). So, why is this? Is there a more efficient way to multiprocess in python?

Comment: This depends on many things, e. g. if your real work code accesses files heavily or if the processes altogether need more memory than available as RAM.

Comment: Ok, so both is not the case. I have one image stack of roughly 150 mb, which is loaded once. The process has quite heavy RAM usage, but I still have resources (60% of 32 gb are in use). Shall I post the "real" code so that you might have a look it at (I don't want to overstretch your help)?

Comment: Maybe you should make this a new question so that other also take a look. This is a different problem than the original one.